# How to remove the edit button on a Master-Detail Template

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I made a project in interface builder with the Master-Detail Template and I'd like to get rid of the edit button.

I wrote (in MasterViewController):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return NO;
}
```

This disables the edit button, however the button is still there.

Then I tried (in the viewDidLoad, after connecting the tableView property to my MasterViewController class):

```
 [self.tableView setEditing:NO];
```

However, the button is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the button altogether. `setEditing` has to do with wether or not the tableview is in edit mode or not, so try:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

In your `viewDidLoad` method.

Also make sure you don't see a line of code in viewDidLoad that looks like:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

If yes, delete or comment it out.

Comment: That helps, thanks...for anyone any looking it was actually self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem; which is part of the template. I had to remove that line (duh)